# C#: Wait for user input inside a class library without freezing graphical user interface

Tags: c#, user-interface, dll, freeze

My goal is to have **one method** inside a class library (.dll)

First we instantiate the class and then we call the method.

This method will :

1. **Draw** a simple GUI ( two buttons ).
2. **STOP** execution and **Wait** user to click Button 1 or Button 2.
3. **Continue** execution and return a value based on what button was pressed.

After execution step 3 the instantiated class will be Destroy.

This class library is instantized in a different environment and the method can be called 1 time only.

My actual blocking points are :

1. If I use a while inside my code the GUI will freeze.
2. If I use Threads the code will continue execution and will not wait for user input.

My question is:

How do you handle this kind of situation? Is there any guideline or predefined architecture for this kind of use cases?

Thank you.

Comment: Should this be windows forms or wpf? For me it sounds like showing a modal dialog, this also 'stops' the execution of the caller.

Comment: This must be a custom made .net framework windows form.

Comment: The system will have to redraw when needed, no?

Comment: No need of redraw. 1 time only drowning.

Comment: In my interpretation point 2 means, the code stops execution until the user clicks a button. This is a typical case for a modal dialog. Simply create a form, add to buttons to it and show the form with [Form.ShowDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=windowsdesktop-5.0). Close the form in the click eventhandler of the buttons.

Comment: Steeeve ! This is incredibly! That was soooooo easy! Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Well, the question is somewhat strange, it was harder to understand than finding a solution ;)

Comment: Thank you again! I check the solution and is exactly what I need ! ( I don’t know how to mark your input as the perfect answer for my problem ) 

Comment: Don't bother upvoting my comments, glad it helped. Normally you could post your solution as an answer, but because this is most probably a homework, do it later, after your teacher/prof has seen it.

Comment:  Sadly this is not a homework. Is just a prove that skipping some pages from the manual can be very dangerous .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is now **solved** thanks to **Steeeve** !

Using Form.ShowDialog(); instead of Form.Show(); will "stops" execution until the user clicks a button.

" This is a typical case for a modal dialog. Simply create a form, add to buttons to it and show the form with . Close the form in the click eventhandler of the buttons." by Steeeve.